# Is there way to get two objects to line up inside of a button in IE7?

Tags: css, xhtml, internet-explorer-7

This bug has been driving me nuts for a few days and I just can't get it to work.

Basically, I have an icon and text inside of a button. I want them to line up correctly, but IE7 stacks them on top of each other. Unless I give the button a specific width, the text and image won't line up correctly. Can anyone help me out? Thanks in advance.

Here's a simple example:

```
<button><div class="test" style="float:left;">image</div>text</button>
```

Comment: different browser will behave differently when you are doing floating then text without defined width. Usually lower versions of IE like 7 behaves badly without width set. you can set width for IE 7 only with IE conditional statement

Comment: That basically sums up the problem, but I'm looking to see if there's a solution for this. I can't set a specific width for each button that has an icon. Not very practical when someone might change the text.

Comment: You could try a `white-space:nowrap` on the button ([jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/thomas_peklak/QZ4PQ/)) - not sure if this is working in your circumstances and I do not have an IE7 ready to test it.

Comment: I tested it, still the same. Thanks anyways.

Comment: you can set the width via js/jquery, if you use white-space:nowrap then you can find the button width with the text only, grab the width of the image inside the button and add that width to the text only width, set it for ie 7 only. I don't think there is a way around this other than setting the width dynamically. maybe you can check the site traffic and see if it is worth it to support ie7. but for the width setting it wouldn't be that much code

Answer (score 0):

If you changed the float to 'display:inline', wouldn't that work?

```
<button><div class="test" style="display:inline">image</div>text</button>
```